# How to count value in column and groupby

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to to get the count of OK & NOK for each *ITCD* & *Indicateur RDV*,
here a sample of my table :

```
_ITCD_ | _Indicateur RDV_ | Week | Workers
OK         OK               41      John
OK         NOK              41      John
NOK        NOK              40      Liam
```

I want to get the count of each workers for each week so here the output result that i want achieve

```
Workers | Week | _ITCD_  | _Indicateur RDV_|
               | OK| NOK | OK | NOK        |
------------------------------------------ |
John      41   | 2 |  0  | 1  |  1         |  
------------------------------------------ |
Liam      40   | 0 |  1  | 0  |  1         |
```

So far i tried melt & crosstab but i didnt achieve to include the other column, same with pivot table & groupby

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lists in [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), combine it with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
df2 = df.melt(['Week', 'Workers'])

pd.crosstab([df2['Week'], df2['Workers']], [df2['variable'], df2['value']])
```

output:

```
variable     _ITCD_    _Indicateur RDV_   
value           NOK OK              NOK OK
Week Workers                              
40   Liam         1  0                1  0
41   John         0  2                1  1
```

Comment: Thank you ! that's what i wanted to achieve